# Symfony2 conventions

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, standards

I was wondering where I can find conventions for Symfony2 and maybe Doctrine. I found the 
[Coding Standards](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html) and the [Conventions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/conventions.html) sections of the documentation.

But I still don't know about things like how to name my controllers - for example ProductController or ProductsController, or how to name my entity classes - Product or Products.

Another thing I'm wondering about now is if there is a convention for naming methods that interact with the database - addProduct or newProduct, editProduct ot updateProduct, deleteProduct or removeProduct.

I'd be very grateful for some articles or resources on the subject, if there are any, because I couldn't find (maybe because I don't know what to search for), or just for answers on the questions I gave as examples.

Thank you very much in advance! :)

Comment: Kind of wish they would open this backup.  There is one not so obvious method naming convention that is basically hard coded into the symfony form component.  It's actually implemented in PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.  I'm sure it's documented somewhere but I have never found it.  In any event, if your entities have private/protected properties then you need accessors with standard prefixes: get,set,is,add,remove

Answer (score 3):

Symfony follows the standards defined in the [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md), [PSR-1](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md) (Coding Standard) and [PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) (Coding Style) documents.

You should also check, 
[How to use Best Practices for Structuring Bundles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html).

**It may also help ...**

[Opensky's Symfony2-coding-standard](https://github.com/opensky/Symfony2-coding-standard) for php code sniffer to check against the Symfony coding standards you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You should also read some code from famous bundles such as FOSUserBundle, you will get great ideas!

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle